# Using WinInet.h to download giving me errors

Tags: c++, c, windows, download, wininet

I want to download with `WinInet.h`, but it's giving me a numerous errors in my new Project. In older projects, this wasn't the case.

Here is my Code:

```
string DownloadString(string URL) {
    HINTERNET interwebs = InternetOpenA("Mozilla/5.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HINTERNET urlFile;
    string rtn;
    if (interwebs) {
        urlFile = InternetOpenUrlA(interwebs, URL.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (urlFile) {
            char buffer[2000];
            DWORD bytesRead;
            do {
                InternetReadFile(urlFile, buffer, 2000, &bytesRead);
                rtn.append(buffer, bytesRead);
                memset(buffer, 0, 2000);
            } while (bytesRead);
            InternetCloseHandle(interwebs);
            InternetCloseHandle(urlFile);
            string p = replaceAll(rtn, "|n", "\r\n");
            return p;
        }
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(interwebs);
    string p = replaceAll(rtn, "|n", "\r\n");
    return p;

}
```

And that are my Includes:

```
#include "c_api.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "termcolor.h"
#include "xor.hpp"
#include <time.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "WinInet.lib")
```

And here you can see the Errors. 
[image: do] 
[image: do]

Comment: So the first thing you need to do is remove code to narrow down the cause of the error. Since the error is in the header file all code after `#include <wininet.h>` should be  irrelevant, so try removing that code first. Then play around with the code that is before `#include <wininet.h>` to see what makes a difference. This is a normal programming skill to have, so look on this as a learning oppotunity. If after playing around you are still stuck, then ask again. At least you'll be in a position to ask a more focussed question.

Comment: You could try to move the `#include <Windows.h>` before including `wininet.h`, it wouldn't be the first time this helped when using multiple Windows headers.

Comment: I already tried that otherwise i woulndt ask here i removed Windows.h now its only giving me 12 Errors. 10 of them are from WinInet.h and 2 of them from fstream.h    https://postimg.cc/V5jgjVx0

Comment: @TizianBöhmakaL337H4x0r by inverting the include (`windows.h` before `wininet.h`), and without including your private headers, the code compile. So you have to check what you are doing in your private headers

Answer (score 2):

You must respect this include sequences (`windows.h` before `wininet.h`):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <wininet.h>  
// ...

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
```